# Low energy LEDs

Tags: led, low-power

What is the lowest energy LEDs (SMT) you know. I am browsing catalogues for days now and I thinking if there is anything on the market really low power.

#edit

I have about 10-15 LEDs on the board. All are giving meaningful information and I cant disable them. As the device is battery operated (rather large battery, bu still battery) so I am looking for something which will give some some light having as low as possible voltage drop and the current.

Comment: this question makes no sense. operate any LED with a lower current, it's still an LED, but a lower power one; therefore, you're looking for the wrong thing, look for the LED with the lowest product of band gap and photons per current. Also, this is a product recommendation question, and hence off-topic.

Comment: All are 100% efficient: what doesn't generate light generates heat. Perhaps you want one that puts out more light than heat?

Comment: I'd recommend you simply rephrase the question: You want to *build* something out of this, and thus, you're not looking for any LED that uses little power (again, no lower bound can really be given, and you'll end up getting recommendations for infrared LEDs, or even Schottky diodes, if power is the only concern); you're looking for an LED to fulfill a certain job while you maximize e.g. battery life time. Describe the problem you're solving before asking for products! (again, the latter is off-topic)

Comment: PJ, you may be looking for something that (at least used to be) is called "high efficiency" LEDs.

Comment: Here's an example of a [green one](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/download_datasheet.php?id=8831702&part-number=APTD1608LZGCK) spec'd as "low power" and 2 mA. I think that's at least similar to what I wanted you to start looking for.

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic, as well.

Comment: Good LEDs can give light that can be perceived in a darkened room with less than 1uA of current. Good LEDs tend to cost a lot more than not-good LEDs and have fewer sources of supply. I suggest considering making the LEDs turn off when they are not required (pushbutton or whatever) so they don't run continuously. If that's not possible you'll need to hit the catalogs, order some samples and figure out what works for you.

Comment: Do you care about the colour? Some colours are more efficient (lumen per watt)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Low power stuff sometimes use LEDs that briefly blink every ten seconds or more.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany price is not the issue in this case. If I could switch them off... but my hands are tied by the specification

Comment: @TEMLIB patterns are also part of the specification. No freedom here. That is the reason of my question.

Comment: are you sure you want lower voltage drop? you will waste more energy powering a tiny red LED from a battery than powering a white LED from a battery. Green is the most visible, which means it can be seen with the least current.

Comment: @dandavis no but I have avaible 1.2V, 1.8V, 2.5, 3.0 & 3.3V on the board.

Comment: Then specify low power LEDs when you buy them.  Using a resistor to limit current to a higher power LED will burn up a lot of energy in the resistor.  You can also pulse LEDs, you know.  Flash them at 500Hz at 10% duty cycle and they'll take only 10% of the power.

Answer (score 2):

An LED uses as much power as you give it. You get to decide. Of course, if you don't give it much power, it won't be very bright.

Answer (score 2):

Red LEDs will be your most efficient in terms of light production.  "High efficiency red leds" will produce more light per mA.

Power consumption is calculated as P = I * V. For instance, a highbrite red LED has a forward voltage of ~1.8V when driven at 18mA.  P = 1.8*0.018 = 32.4mW of power.  Also watch out for power loss in your current limiting resistor or LED driver.  Best way to save power when driving LEDs is to reduce the current, but that reduces brightness.

You may find you are losing more power in your power supply stages.

Source: I work for a manufacturing company that mainly produces red LED displays.

Comment: Actually white LEDS are more visible at same low power and efficacy due to eye efficiency near between yellow and blue.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient LEDS use narrow beams to amplify light but min If for chemical corrosion is 5% rated . You can get 20Cd Red Yellow LEDs that run off 1mA that produce 500 mcd at 1mA by choosing 10 CD 5 mm LEDs.

Then choose series R for max If and string voltage at 1.85 to 1.9V per LED on low battery.

Answer (score 0):

LEDs that are attached on PCBs are all mainly produce the same amount of light at the same power consumption except when color is changed. So in case you would like to minimize battery consumption you either decrease number of LEDs that are attached to the board, choose the least power consuming LED color, or you can power those LEDs on 50-70% of their total power.

Choosing a more bright LED for the same color occurs only when LEDs are intended for lighting purposes not just blinking. You could find different LED manufacturers that are competing to produce a more lumen/watt LEDs to prove their strength on the market. and that occurs only for high power LEDs.

Answer (score 0):

To save energy choose the most efficient LEDs you can find and run them at a power level that gives sufficient brightness.

LEDS run at a lower current are proportionately dimmer than at full datasheet current and tend to last well beyond the lifetime given in the datasheet.

consider using lenses and reflectors to concentrate the light form the LEDs as apropriate for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any LED will run at 3.3V or less, if that's what you have on your board.  Red ones require about 1.5 to 1.6V, and at the other end the spectrum, blue ones take about 3.0 to 3.3V.

If you want low brightness and low current draw, increase the current limiting resistor, rather than changing the LED.  Small LEDs may be specified up to perhaps 20mA maximum.  But you don't need anywhere near that to make a suitable indicator lamp.  1mA would still produce a decent glow.  You may even get away with reducing it down further if the LEDs only need to be viewed in subdued light.